# skimage flood_fill fill the whole images

Tags: python, scikit-image, flood-fill

These are my code for flood filling the my image, so what i want was just the outerspace that got color value of 50, but instead everything is grayed out.

```
checkers = invert(cv2.imread('skeleton2.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))

filled_checkers = flood_fill(checkers, (0, 0),50,tolerance=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 5))

ax[0].imshow(checkers, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=0, vmax=255)
ax[0].set_title('Original')

ax[1].imshow(filled_checkers, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=0, vmax=255)

ax[1].set_title('After flood fill')

plt.show()
```

What I want https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuQAO.jpg

What I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2pd0.jpg

Comment: The flood fill implementation you're using apparently considers the neighborhood of a pixel to be eight other pixels, including the diagonal ones.  With the one-pixel wide lines in your source image, the flood can therefore "leak" diagonally between pixels in sloped areas of the lines.  You want to flood with a 4-pixel neighborhood, instead.  I don't see any such option with skimage, but cv2's `FloodFill()` does have a `flags` parameter that can specify this.

Comment: thank you, that's very helpful. i think i'll go with the cv2's implementation instead

Comment: The parameter exists in scikit-image and is called `connectivity`. We use this parameter (1-, 2-, ..., ndim-connectivity) rather than 4/8-neighborhood because it generalises to 3D images and higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `connectivity=1` as a parameter. See the [documentation for flood fill](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.flood_fill):

> selem: ndarray, optional
>
> A structuring element used to determine the neighborhood of each evaluated pixel. It must contain only 1’s and 0’s, have the same number of dimensions as image. If not given, all adjacent pixels are considered as part of the neighborhood (fully connected).
>
> connectivity: int, optional
>
> A number used to determine the neighborhood of each evaluated pixel. Adjacent pixels whose squared distance from the center is less than or equal to connectivity are considered neighbors. Ignored if selem is not None.

The examples section in the docstring also contains examples explaining the connectivity.

Comment: So glad I found your answer as this deals with the problem of the fill spilling out through the diagonal spaces. Which was not immediately obvious to me from reading the docs. Cheers